# Check if Cordova/Phonegap is correct

Tags: android, cordova, navigator

A simple question, how i can check if cordova is properly accessible and working in my html index file in android.
I tried searching for some syntax or code that can confirm but alas...

There are some functions that I am not able to access. Like navigator.connection.type gives me that type not defined of null..
So I am wondering if there is any way to check.

Thanks..

EDIT 1

```
$(document).one('pageinit', function(event) {

        registerElementEvents();
        validateFields();
        // Check Internet Connection
        checkConnection();
});

function checkConnection() {
    //alert(window.top.navigator);
    var objects = window.top.navigator;
    for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key];
    //alert(value);
}
    if( !navigator.network )
     {
         // set the parent windows navigator network object to the child window
         navigator.network = window.top.navigator.network;
     }

    // return the type of connection found
   return ( (navigator.network.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null || 
          navigator.network.connection.type === "unknown" ) ? false : true );
}
```

Comment: `navigator.connection.type` requires a plugin to be installed as well. Have you installed (or configured) the `network-information` plugin in your app?

Comment: Ohh..I don't think I have..can you please provide me with a link or similar?? And any sample that you might have..I was checking the actual cordova js and they have network methods

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you working with? Pre 3.x has all of the device apis included. 3.0+ they are have been broken up into plugins. If you are using the cordova client (local) use `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`

Comment: My cordova version is 2.2.0 Thats why I was thinking

Comment: Ok, then you wouldn't need to install anything else. Can you provide the part of your JS that runs on load?

Comment: but still it gives error.. I was trying to search for any steps to follow which can be used to utilize the plugin but it's so vague.. DO you have any steps or similar which can be followed to use plugins in phone gap

Comment: At this point I would need to see some of your code to debug the issue. It may have to do with calling to navigator before the `deviceready` event has fired, but I need to see some code.

Comment: defntly mate.. I have added code base in initial question..Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50163/discussion-between-kaushik-ray-and-dawson-loudon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of way to check 
 you can use the `alert("your message");` so that you get a popup window in the function that 
you want to work

Another way is using `console.log("TESTING");` which will generate a log file.  you can trace the log file too

for your nxt question regarding the connection type you can see and use this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Answer (score 1):

So reviewing the code it looks like the issue is that there is no check for the `deviceready` event.

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad">
```

JS:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
}

function deviceReady() {
    registerElementEvents();
    validateFields();
    // Check Internet Connection
    checkConnection();
}
```

Comment: THere is some issue ..My body onload method never kicked off.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I make use of a boolean value. When it is true, PhoneGap is propperly loaded.

`// device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.deviceReady = true;
}`